# Which items should I use to maximise Ra's Solar Blessing ability?

Tags: smite

I want to play Ra as a healer.  Which items can I use to maximise the healing for team mates?

I would guess some items that reduce cooldown times, but is there anything more or specific that I should include in my build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General Guidelines

*Usually*, magical gods that are looking to optimize their healing will prioritize power, MP5, and cooldown reduction in some way. Power will help determine how strong your heals are, cooldown reduction will help determine how quickly you can press your heal button again, and MP5 will help determine how often you can press the heal button until you run out of mana. There is hard cap on cooldown reduction of 40%, and while there is also a cap on MP5 I believe, it isn't usually particularly relevant because it's pretty high and if you are going to reach it, you'll do so on accident.

To this point, the first item most players that are prioritizing healing pick is ***Chronos' Pendant***. It provides a healthy 75 power, but more importantly it provides 25 MP5 and 20% cooldown reduction. I typically play Assault mode, and this is almost always the first item any mage-type god takes, but there's no exceptions I know of when it comes to mage healers.

### Healer-focused items

There are two note-worthy items that enhance the abilities of a healing mage. The first is the ***Rod of Asclepius***, which provides 75 power, 250 health, and 10% movement speed (which is quite great for Ra, but useful in general). The really unique thing about this item is the aura it grants, which increases the healing and health regeneration of allies within 70 units by 25%.

The second item, which may be more situational for certain gods, is called ***Lotus Crown***. It provides 60 power, 20 physical protection, and 20 MP5. It also has a passive ability that grants a +20 physical and magical protection buff for 5 seconds on any god affected by your heal abilities, although it cannot activate on the same target within 10 seconds. This is *really good* for healing mages that heal in a radius around themselves, since it means they'd have to be near danger to heal in combat. On Ra, this is more situational, but still useful, especially if you could put the physical protection or MP5 it grants to good use.

### Boots

The only two boots I get as a healer are ***Shoes of the Magi*** (45 power, 10 magical penetration), or ***Shoes of Focus*** (30 power, 250 mana, 10% cooldown). I decide which to buy based on the enemy team composition. If there are a lot of physical champs on the opposing team, then I'll buy the ***Shoes of the Magi***. Even though it lacks the cooldown reduction that the ***Shoes of Focus*** grants, I'll get ***Shoes of the Magi*** because I know that I'll get a physical defensive item later on, and there's a great option that comes with a lot of cooldown reduction (see below).

### Late-game items

From there, the rest of your items will be highly situational and depend on the specific environment of your game. More power and cooldown reduction will help your heals. But you also need to be able to survive your lane and team fights. As an assault player, I can tell you that, depending on the enemy team comp, I will often pick up a physical defensive item (***Breastplate of Valor*** for it's 75 physical protections and 20% cooldown reduction), or a magical defensive item (***Pestilence*** for it's anti-healing aura for your opponents or ***Bulwark of Hope*** for additional survivability).

Then, I'll generally prioritize either power or cooldown reduction. If I have ***Chronos' Pendant*** and ***Breastplate of Valor***, then I'm capped on cooldown reduction and will focus on power, with ***Rod of Tahuti*** being a prime choice if I can finish buying it in a reasonable amount of time. If I don't have the breastplate, then I might look at ***Pythagorem's Piece*** for the extra 10% cooldown reduction it provides if I still feel the need to cap it.

I'll probably also invest in magical penetration, although that's not always a given. Be aware of what the enemy team is building themselves. If some enemy players are stacking some magical defense items, then look into getting a ***Obsidian Shard***, which allows you to penetrate 33% of your target's magical defenses, or some other penetration item you'd prefer.

There's some other situational items as well, depending on circumstances, that you might want. ***Divine Ruin*** is a great item if enemy healers are giving your team trouble. ***Warlock's Sash*** is nice if it's available in your game mode, and a good case can be made to picking it up early in the game. ***Soul Reaver*** can help damage those high-hitpoint targets. None of this really helps with healing specifically, but Ra can also be a pretty powerful offensive god with great range. Once you've got your core healing items, don't forget that you also have to deal damage in team fights too, and these items still provide healthy amounts of power while providing you with more utility to help your team.

Note: While you're asking specifically for Ra, a lot of this answer can be applied to other healing gods. However, Guan Yu is a physical god that is considered a healer. Almost none of these items apply to him, although some of the strategies do.

Comment: Chronos' Pendant, Rod of Asclepius and Shoes of Focus are so far proving good items.  I will play some more with different variations.

Comment: if you tend to play with friends, or use voice chat to coordinate with a team, the people you are healing could benefit by using certain items too, such as the [gauntlet of thebes](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Gauntlet_of_Thebes).

Comment: @Dpeif: Sure. Although, I would expect almost everyone except perhaps Hercules players would skip right over that item. It really only grants health and health regen... and nothing else.

Comment: @Ellesedil agreed, it is an underwhelming item